# Add textbox value to Npgsqlconnection

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have multiple databases and Im writing a searchprogram for those databases.
For now, I need to change my code everytime I want to change database.

My connection looks like this:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=WA150;Database=Win_1054;Username=postgres;password=*****");
```

I want to change hostname and database from a textbox, can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I missing something or this is what you want?

```
string connectionString = string.Format("Host={0};Database={1};Username=postgres;password=*****", 
    txtHost.Text.Trim(), txtDatabase.Text.Trim());

NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Of course, you should add some input validation to make sure `txtHost` and `txtDatabase` have correct values..